# How to pass arguments in netstat command?

Tags: vbscript, netstat

I am using a `netstat` command in VBScript to find out the ports which are listening. As a process, I am reading the IP address and port number from two variables.

A file contains an IP address, port number which were separated by commas as shown below:

```
10.x.x.x,3389
```

Like there are multiple IPs and port numbers existing in a file. By using array concept I am fetching the IP address and port number from the file using `myarray(0)` and `myarray(1)` variables.

My code looks like this:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim port_number, port_status, port_conn_ip, portread, portfile, PSExec, PCIExec

objShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin"

Set objfile = objFSO.openTextFile("C:\IBM\port_mon\list_of_ports.txt")

Do until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    portread = objfile.ReadLine
    portfile = Split(portread, ",")

    Set PSExec = objShell.Exec("%comspec% /k ""netstat -an |find ""myvalue(0) ""|find ""myvalue(1)""|awk ""{print $4}""""")

    port_status = PSExec.Stdout.ReadLine

    WScript.Echo port_status
```

But here `myvalue(0)` and `myvalue(1)` are not updating with IP address or port number. I also tried to provide like `" & myvalue(0) & "` but this also didn't give me any result. Always the output is empty.

As a background work, I have verified the connectivity of IP address and port number both are in connected and established state.

Answer (score 0):

The string concatenation approach was the right thing to do. VBScript doesn't expand variables inside strings. However, the name of your array variable is `portfile`, not `myvalue` (or `myarray`). Put `Option Explicit` at the beginning of your script to detect mistakes like that.

Change your code to something like this, and it should do what you expect:

```
cmd = "%comspec% /k ""netstat -an | find """ & portfile(0) & """ | find """ & _
      portfile(1) & """ | awk ""{print $4}"""""
Set PSExec = objShell.Exec(cmd)
```

BTW, you don't need to call `find` twice for address and port (assuming that both refer to a remote host). Just filter for `IP:port`:

```
cmd = "%comspec% /k ""netstat -an | find """ & portfile(0) & ":" & _
      portfile(1) & """ | awk ""{print $4}"""""
Set PSExec = objShell.Exec(cmd)
```

And as I mentioned in the comments to your previous question, you also don't need to print a column with `awk` and then read and compare the output. Just use the `Run` method, add another `find` step to check if the line contains the text "ESTABLISHED", and then check the exit code of the command.

```
cmd = "%comspec% /c ""netstat -an | find """ & portfile(0) & ":" & _
      portfile(1) & """ | find ""ESTABLISHED"""""
rc = objShell.Run(cmd, 0, True)

If rc = 0 Then
    'connection established
Else
    'no established connection found
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar that worked. Now how can I append the output to a log file like

`wscript.echo("Connection established") >> "C:\output.log"`

When I execute the above it is giving me the syntax error